# Pigeon Principle of Dirichlet

Tags: elementary-set-theory

***Lemma***- **Pigeon Principle of Dirichlet**

If $n \in \omega$ and $f: n \overset{\text{1-1}}{\rightarrow} n$ then $f: n \underset{\text{surjective}}{\rightarrow} n$.

Proof:

We suppose that $f: n \to n$ is not surjective.
Then there is a $m \in n=\{0,1,2, \dots, n-1 \}$ such that $\forall l \in n: f(l) \neq m$.
So there is a $k \in \{0,1, \dots, n-1\}-\{m\}$ and there are $j,j' \in \{0,1, \dots, n-1 \}, j \neq j'$ such that $f(j)=k=f(j')$. Thus, $f$ is not injective, contradiction.

In this case the function $f$ has the same domain and range.

But wouldn't the Pigeon Principle of Dirichlet also hold if we would have for example $2n$ as the range?

Comment: I am little confused now.. Could you explain me at the proof how we conclude that since $\forall l \in n: f(l) \neq m$ it has to hold that $f(j)=f(j')=k, \text{ for } j,j' \in \{0,1, \dots, n-1 \}, j \neq j'$ ?

Comment: No. There are 1-1 functions $n\to 2n$ that are not surjective.

Comment: yeah @HagenvonEitzen is right, I didn't read the question properly. you should consider some example, like the inclusion of $\{0\}$ into $\{0,1\}$ lol

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So does this lemma only hold when the domain and the range are the same?

Answer (score 1):

The *pigeon principle* says that if $ f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a application from a finite set $X$ to a finite set $Y$ such that $X$ has strictly more elements than $Y$ has, then $f$ is not injective. Indeed, would it be injective it would induce a bijection from $X$ to the subset $f(X)$ of $Y$, and this would be absurd for cardinal reasons.

Comment: At the proof do we consider the function $f(x)=x$ ?
$$$$
Does this mean:  $\forall l \in n: f(l) \neq m$ that the function $f$ has $n-1$ possible values?

Comment: What you have just asked does not make any sense. To consider the function $f(x)=x$, you should at least have $Y\subseteq X$, which is not stated in what I just wrote. I suggest you stop trying doing mathematics for a while and ask yourself the following : if you have two boxes and three pencils, and if you put all pencils in these two boxes, would you have one of the boxes containing two pencils ? Understand this, and then all the rest will be crystal clear to you.

Comment: Our domain is $n=\{0,1, \dots, n-1 \}$ and our range is $\{ 0,1, \dots, n-1 \}$, right? We have that $\forall l \in \text{ domain }: f(l) \neq m$. So we consider that the range is $\{ 0,1, \dots, n-1\} \setminus \{ m\}$. Now the domain contains $n$ elements and the range $n-1$. That means that two elements of the domain are mapped to the same element of the range. Or have I understood it wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Nice!!! And could you also tell me if the lemma holds only when we have the same range and domain?

Comment: Why do you think there is the word "strictly" in the statement of the lemma ?...